# Async not working Atom TypeScript

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

I am learning TypeScript using Atom IDE.

Question is, when I try the below code

```
async function fn1() {
    throw new Error("Not implemented yet");
}
```

I get an error

> An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.

However if I paste the code in 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html

it compiles correctly . Moreover I am not getting any suggestions when I use Promise in Atom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working TypeScript config (`tsconfig.json`) which I use as my minimal config for webpacked TypeScript:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "types": ["jquery"],
    "lib": ["dom", "es2015"],
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

And here is the Node.js-targetting version:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "../dist/server",
    "types": ["node"],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "noImplicitAny": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "filesGlob": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ],
  "files": [
    "server.ts"
  ],
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are targeting ES5, you need to make sure you include the appropriate lib values in your compiler options.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["dom", "es2015.promise", "es5"]
    }
}
```

...as well as introducing any necessary polyfill. Please see the downlevel async documentation on the [TypeScript release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html).